# Using XML as a database. How to generate id for my record just like we have auto increment in SQL?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xslt, code-behind

I am using XML as a database. I want to generate `Id` for my record, `Id` will be auto increment like a SQL Server identity id.

How can I generate such an `id`?

My XML source Look like this:

Data.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CATALOG>
  <orderByTitleDesc />
  <orderByTitleDesc />
  <orderByTitleDesc />
  <orderByTitleDesc />
  <orderByTitleDesc />
  <orderByTitleDesc />
  <orderByTitleDesc />
  <orderByTitleDesc />

  <CD>
    <LocationID>Test121</LocationID>
    <ChangeValueFor>TestFor India</ChangeValueFor>
    <Banner>India</Banner>
    <DataEntry>Yes</DataEntry>
    <LocalView>Yes</LocalView>
    <Export>Yes</Export>
    <View>Illions</View>
    <ActiveView>Kentency</ActiveView>
    <HelpFile>Finger</HelpFile>
    <Location01>Chicken</Location01>
    <Location02>India</Location02>
    <Location03>USa</Location03>
    <Location04>Africa</Location04>
    <Location05>USa</Location05>
    <Location06>Ellions</Location06>
    <Location07>UK</Location07>
    <Location08>States</Location08>
    <Location09>OF</Location09>
    <Server>31 March 2014 testing with font</Server>
    <Server2>171.21.102.11</Server2>
    <Server3>test2</Server3>
    <CodeBase>Ser</CodeBase>
    <CodeBase2>31 amrch testing for font</CodeBase2>
    <CodeBase3>hellow</CodeBase3>
    <ClassiscID>clsid:ACAC1200-0BBE-499A-A9E9-5F334DBC8E89</ClassiscID>
    <ClassiscID2>clsid:ACAC1200-0BBE-499A-A9E9-5F334DBC8E89</ClassiscID2>
    <ClassiscID3>this</ClassiscID3>
    <Theme>class</Theme>
    <Theme2>Theme2</Theme2>
    <Theme3>Ser</Theme3>
    <Theme4>InkIndia</Theme4>
    <Theme5>InkIndia</Theme5>
    <Theme6>VashnoDevi</Theme6>
  </CD>
</CATALOG>
```

I can't give the user to make his own id to enter in the textbox. I want user to add a record and id generates automatically like in SQL Server. How do I do it?

Please let me know. Thanks in advance, guys.

Comment: Which API are you using for managing your XML Data ? Linq TO XML or ADO.Net by using DataSet and DataTable.

Comment: ADO .Net using DataSet and Data Table

Comment: Have you create your DataTable via code?

Comment: Yes I have done that I am able to get all the values in the dataset at the time when i need to addedit it .I am clicking on hyperlink to edit the record and than to save in data.xml....Thats why I need a record on the basis of id  which has to be unique.Right now i am getting it on the basis of location id in data.xml

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create some Id that is unique you can use

```
System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
```

It is a global unique identifier, that is not auto incremented but serves well as identifer even in multithreading environments.

Answer (score 0):

You could add an attribute to your CATALOG node, possibly called count. When you add a new CD node (which I assume is the type of record you are adding to the CATALOG) you could use the current count as the Id for the new record and then increment it.

You have this marked with an ASP.NET tag, which means you could possibly run into a multithreading problem using this solution depending on how you code this. But, as a basic solution, this should work.

Answer (score 0):

you can keep a counter in your server and increment it each time someone enters a record to the DB.
or read all the nodes and count them on each insertion.

take a look at the following links that might help:

http://forums.asp.net/t/573255.aspx?Auto+Increment+unique+ID+in+XML+file

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaevans/2003/03/28/using-autoincrement-for-an-xml-document/